# How to use higher-order constructs in a particular case

Tags: haskell, option-type

I want to write a function that takes two `Maybe Int` parameters and returns the minimum of them if they are both `Just number`, and 'the other' if either of them is `Nothing`.  I'm not satisfied with my first attempt:

```
maybeMin :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
maybeMin Nothing arr = arr
maybeMin ell Nothing = ell
maybeMin ell@(Just l) arr@(Just r) = if l < r then ell else arr
```

As an optimisation I don't want to create a new value in the third case;  i.e., I don't want to write

```
maybeMin ell@(Just l) arr@(Just r) = Just $ if l < r then l else r
```

The above code seems clunky and it seems to me that I ought to be able to exploit the fact that `Maybe` is an instance of `Functor`, `Applicative` or `Monad`.  However, my best attempt to go higher-order doesn't do the same thing:

```
maybeMin ell arr = ell >>= (\l -> arr >>= (\r -> if l < r then ell else arr))
```

because it will return `Nothing` if *either* operand be `Nothing`.

Is there an elegant way to do what I want?

Comment: I’m not quite sure I quite understand your problem… personally, I don’t see anything wrong with doing `Just $ if l < r then l else r`.

Comment: @bradm -- nothing wrong _per se_ but it's a lot of code for something fairly simple, and it unnecessarily requires the creation of a new `Maybe` instance.

Comment: I wouldn’t be so confident that it creates a new `Maybe` — due to laziness, they may end up sharing their values. And Haskell data types are very lightweight, so it probably doesn’t even take up very much space. If you’re concerned, you can always profile your program with `+RTS -s` and see how much space is being used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You looked at `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad`, but you may want to check out [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative).  As an example of its use, `Just 3 <|> Nothing` will yield `Just 3` and not `Nothing`.

For your particular use, if you want a one-liner, you could try:

```hs
maybeMin l r = min l r <|> l <|> r
```

Just to break that down, we first calculate `min l r`, which uses the `Ord` instance of `Maybe` to give the minimum of `l` and `r` if both are `Just` values.  If this works, then the computation stops there, but if either one isn't `Just`, then we check to see if `l` is a `Just` value.  If it is, then that is the result, and if not, we end up returning `r` as the result.

Comment: You don’t even need `min <$> l <*> r`: `Maybe` is `Ord`, so you can just do `min l r`.

Comment: @bradrn Right you are!  I'll update my answer.

Comment: So it comes down to `maybeMin = min` -- it doesn't get much more simple than that!  Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelrestoreMonicaCellio Actually, it doesn’t! `maybeMin = min` will return `Nothing` when either argument is `Nothing`; instead, you want to return `Nothing` only when _both_ arguments are `Nothing`.

Comment: @bradm -- Oops, yes, correct;  well spotted.